# How to define the regular expression I want?

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to loop through files. Some files with a specific name should be used inside a function. It looks like:

```
func <- function(number){
  fileList <- list.files(pattern=c("^Start_", number, "_end.csv"))
}
```

I only want to use the file with exactly the right number in the file name. When I run the function with `10` as parameter now, it also takes the files with `100` or `1000` in the filename.

This is what I already tried:

```
pattern=c("^Start_", number, "_end.csv")
pattern=c("^Start_", number, "^_end.csv")
pattern=c("^Start_", "^", number, "$", "_end.csv")
```

All of these patterns also use the files with `100` and `1000` in the filename, when I run the function with `10` as parameter.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I don't always want to use '10' in the file name. The number is dependent of the given number when the function is called. But it's already solved, thanks anyway!

Comment: I don't get this. Why do you need a regex if you know the exact file name?

Comment: Why regex? `myData <- read.table(paste0("Start_", number, "_end.csv"))`

Comment: Because I also have files with 20, 30, 40 etc in the filename. And I want to use that files also in this function, in a later function call. That 10 was just an example

Comment: I understand this. But you still know the file name exactly during each function call. There is no need for a regular expression in such a case. In fact, I don't even get why you call `list.files`.

Comment: @Roland Now I can simply run func(10), or func(50). I think that's easier. Perhaps there are other options, but I just think this is easy when calling the function

Comment: I don't know what you are doing but you could simply use `func <- function(number){
  fileList <-  paste0("Start_", number, "_end.csv")
}` and it would give you the same result (except if the file doesn't exits, but that can be tested with `file.exists`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pattern` parameter to `list.files` should take a single regex *string*, not a vector of strings.  Try this version:

```
func <- function(number) {
    fileList <- list.files(pattern=paste0("^Start_", number, "_end\\.csv$"))
}
```

But given that the regex pattern you are using be fixed, there isn't much point in using regex.  However, if you wanted to match a series of IDs in one go, e.g. 20, 30, and 40, then regex becomes more useful:

```
ids <- c(20, 30, 40)
regex <- paste(ids, collapse="|")
fileList <- list.files(pattern=paste0("^Start_(", regex, ")_end\\.csv$"))
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem! (However, it also seems to work with the vector I used, when I add '\\' after 'end'.) But thanks for solving the problem!

Comment: Know it doesn't become more useful then. It might be useful if you match `[123456789]{1}0{1}`.

Comment: Not really.  From a script/code maintenance point of view, another reader would have a much easier time seeing a visible list of whitelisted files (that is, unless the intention is to use a blanket pattern to match a very large number of files).

Comment: I agree. But if you have that list, you don't need to maintain a regex.

Comment: Once I started off with a problem.  Then I discovered regex.  And now, I have multiple problems `:-)`